# How to stop supabase which is running on localhost 3000?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I wanted to know what supabase is so I installed it using this local development guide [enter link description here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/local-development)

it was few weeks back, i was simply checking port 3000 and supabase is running i have removed all supabase related folder but still its running. can someone help me understand why its still running and how to stop it.

Comment: use `npx kill-port 3000`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys i found the solution. it was cache in the browser which was loading. I deleted history, cache and cookies. now if i open my browser and go to localhost:3000 i can see 'This site can’t be reached' message.

thanks @Mansueli and @ahmad

Answer (score 0):

To stop running supabase, you can use the CLI [stop command](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/cli/supabase-stop):

`supabase stop`

Deleting folders without stopping will keep the current instance running.

You can always use [htop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596830/kill-process-with-htop) (linux) and of follow [this guide](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201276) (macOS) to stop the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted the folder, then the only way to stop Supabase is by manually stopping and removing the containers with Docker.

This can be done through a combination of `docker ps` and `docker rm CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]`